# Scala + Slick + Accord - Custom value class types not working. Just a bad approach?

Tags: scala, slick, implicit-conversion

I am still pretty new to Scala and looking at using Slick.

I also am looking at Accord (github.com/wix/accord) for validation.

Accord's validation seems to be on objects as a whole, but I want to be able to define validators for field types, so I've thought of using type aliasing using value classes so that I can easily re-use validations across various case classes that use those field types.

So, I've defined the following:

```
object FieldTypes {
  implicit class ID(val i: Int) extends AnyVal
  implicit class UserPassword(val s: String) extends AnyVal
  implicit class Email(val s: String) extends AnyVal
  implicit class Name(val s: String) extends AnyVal
  implicit class OrgName(val s: String) extends AnyVal
  implicit class OrgAlias(val s: String) extends AnyVal
}

package object validators {
  implicit val passwordValidator = validator[UserPassword] { _.length is between(8,255) }
  implicit val emailValidator = validator[Email]  { _ is notEmpty }
  implicit val nameValidator = validator[Name] { _ is notEmpty }
  implicit val orgNameValidator = validator[OrgName] { _ is notEmpty }
  implicit val teamNameValidator = validator[TeamName] { _ is notEmpty }
}

case object Records {
  import FieldTypes._

  case class OrganizationRecord(id: ID, uuid: UUID, name: OrgName, alias: OrgAlias)
  case class UserRecord(id: ID, uuid: UUID, email: Email, password: UserPassword, name: Name)
  case class UserToOrganizationRecord(userId: ID, organizationId: ID)
}

class Tables(implicit val p: JdbcProfile) {
  import FieldTypes._
  import p.api._


  implicit object JodaMapping extends GenericJodaSupport(p)

  case class LiftedOrganizationRecord(id: Rep[ID], uuid: Rep[UUID], name: Rep[OrgName], alias: Rep[OrgAlias])
  implicit object OrganizationRecordShape extends CaseClassShape(LiftedOrganizationRecord.tupled, OrganizationRecord.tupled)

  class Organizations(tag: Tag) extends Table[OrganizationRecord](tag, "organizations") {
    def id = column[ID]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
    def uuid = column[UUID]("uuid", O.Length(36, varying=false))
    def name = column[OrgName]("name", O.Length(32, varying=true))
    def alias = column[OrgAlias]("alias", O.Length(32, varying=true))
    def * = LiftedOrganizationRecord(id, uuid, name, alias)
  }
  val organizations = TableQuery[Organizations]
}
```

Unfortunately, I clearly misunderstand or overestimate the power of Scala's implicit conversions. My `passwordValidator` doesn't seem to recognize that there is a `length` property to `UserPassword` and my `*` declaration on my `Organizations` table doesn't seem to think that it complies to the shape defined in `LiftedOrganizationRecord`.

Am I just doing something really dumb here on the whole? Should I not be even trying to use these kinds of custom types and simply use standard types instead, defining my validators in a better way? Or is this an okay way of doing things, but I've just forgotten something simple?

Any advice would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some helpful people on the scala gitter channel, I realized that the core mistake was a misunderstanding of the conversion direction for value classes. I had understood it to be ValueClass -> WrappedValueType, but it's actually WrappedValueType -> ValueClass. Thus, Slick wasn't seeing, as an exmaple, ID as an Int.